# Special permission "WiFi control" permission inactive

Tags: applications, wi-fi, permissions

Special access "WiFi control" permissions on Samsung S6Lite (Android 12, 2022) can not be toggled on or off for all apps (system or non-systems apps; there was just one adjustable - Google Photos). It looks like something preventing a user to do so. I see the blue toggle icons, but they are sort of dimmed and I can not interact.

Any suggestions what's blocking?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question. But you can try to change `CHANGE_WIFI_STATE` AppOp permission using app: [PMX](https://github.com/mirfatif/PermissionManagerX). Introduction here: [What are manifest permissions and AppOps?](https://mirfatif.github.io/IAnswers/android_appop_manifest_permissions). Disclosure: both links belong to me.

Comment: I can change CHANGE_WIFI_STATE with ADB. The question is: What blocks on the user interface level? Because in all other devices I new there were nothing preventing controlling "WiFi control" permissions. But thank you for reference to your app.